# How to make a book using Jekyll on github.io

Tags: github, jekyll

I have about 1000 regular static html pages in the GitHub repository (book). I regularly edit these pages using a special program. Each page contains only content; no header, footer or table of contents.
I want to use Jekyll to host them on Github Pages so that each page has a header, footer and a navigation block - a tree-like table of contents on the left side of browser. The table of contents is also a prepared static html file, common for the entire book.

The easiest way is to use frames, but this is not considered the best option.

I want the result to be something like https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/

I have scanned github (search all repositories for _config.yml file) but have not found any similar use of Jekyll.
Can I do something like this using Jekyll?

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal use-case for a static site generator like Jekyll:

- You might need to convert your content to Markdown or clean them up depending on the HTML
- Each page has a common layout with the header, footer and navigation
- You can make a separate page for table of contents by iterating over your pages inside a separate template

There's not really a concise answer here, short of learning more of Jekyll's feature set to become familiar with the concepts referenced above:

- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/
- https://cloudcannon.com/community/learn/jekyll-101/

Here's a template with a live demo that is made for hosting a book. You could use this as a starting point: https://github.com/CloudCannon/author-jekyll-template